# Photoshop CS4 path question

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-cs4

I'm having a problem with the CS4 path tool:
I created a closed path but it's outlined only. how can I change it to filled mode?
I don't mean just make a selection and fill it, but keeping the filled path and possibility to edit it.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the shape layers option. On the tool bar with the Pen Tool selected make sure that this box is clicked.

[image]